# FQL: Fetch friends of a friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

How could I fetch the friends of a friend of mine with FQL or something other of the FB-APIs?
At the normal website of Facebook it's possible to see the friends of a friend of mine
if I visit his profile and add `?sk=friends` to the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [FQL docs on the friends table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/)

> the friends of friends cannot be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to access a friend's friends you'll get this message:

```
"Can only lookup for the logged in user 
or the logged in user's friends 
that are users of your app."
```

So you can only retrieve a friend's friends who have authorized your app.

Answer (score 0):

Friends of friend can access only when one friend of your friend, your friend and you (loged user) use same app and give permission to access there data.