# Fetch Facebook friends in android

Tags: android, facebook

I am working on an android app in which i need to login with Facebook and fetch facebook friends.

I am using below code for fetching facebook friends:

public class FriendsRequestListener implements RequestListener {

```
/**
 * Called when the request to get friends has been completed.
 * Retrieve and parse and display the JSON stream.
 */
public void onComplete(final String response) {
    try {
        // process the response here: executed in background thread
        Log.d("Facebook-Example-Friends Request", "response.length(): " + 
                response.length());
        Log.d("Facebook-Example-Friends Request", "Response: " + response);

        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray d = json.getJSONArray("data");
        int l = (d != null ? d.length() : 0);
        Log.d("Facebook-Example-Friends Request", "d.length(): " + l);

        for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
            JSONObject o = d.getJSONObject(i);
            String n = o.getString("name");
            String id = o.getString("id");
        }

        // Only the original owner thread can touch its views

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
    }
}

@Override
public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

The way to call this class:

```
mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
                mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", new FriendsRequestListener());
```

The problem is that my code is not doing anything on call of above code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FQL: Fetch friends of a friend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872631/fql-fetch-friends-of-a-friend)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this api [https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/me/friends?fields=picture,id,username&limit=${limit}&access_token=${accessToken}](https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/me/friends?fields=picture,id,username&limit=$%7Blimit%7D&access_token=$%7BaccessToken%7D)

this is a v1.0 api which allows user to fetch all friends list

Answer (score -1):

To get all your facebook friends list you need to get "taggable_friends"

```
GraphRequestAsyncTask r = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(fbToken,
        "/me/taggable_friends", new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                //here you can parse the response
            }
        }
```

`fbToken` is your token from login. However, facebook uses paging, so you need to get the next page and then next value from friends request so you can parse it.

```
response.getJSONObject("paging").getString("next");
```

to get next page users using StringRequest

```
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, next,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                JSONObject friends = null;
                try {
                    friends = new JSONObject(response);
                    parseResponse(friends);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    }
```

Check the full code  [Facebook friends list](https://github.com/sallySalem/Facebook-Friends-list)